# Sticky Header Shrinks jQuery and CSS Tricks

Tags: jquery, css, menu, responsive, sticky

First of all, I'm newbie at css,html and js (you can understand just looking at my codes xD) However, I want to get fancy stuff like many paid wordpress plug-ins do. So I used several plug-ins with weird parameter arrange boxes (that changed my inline code that still i do not understand). Neither one has helped me completely. I've decided to put effort to make this thing with codes.

So here is my code :

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('#site-header').addClass('shrink');
    $('#site-logo').addClass('shrink');
    $('#site-navigation-wrap').addClass('shrink');
    $('#oceanwp-mobile-menu-icon').addClass('shrink');
  } else {
    $('#site-header').removeClass('shrink');
    $('#site-logo').removeClass('shrink');
    $('#site-navigation-wrap').removeClass('shrink');
    $('#oceanwp-mobile-menu-icon').removeClass('shrink');
  }
});
```

```css
#site-header {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#site-header.shrink {
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: .90;
  height: 50px;
}

#site-logo.clr.shrink {
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  margin-top: -25px;
}

#site-navigation-wrap.shrink {
  margin-top: -20px;
}

#site-header.shrink,
#site-header,
#site-logo.clr,
#site-logo.clr.shrink,
#site-navigation-wrap,
#site-navigation-wrap.shrink {
  transition: .3s all ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .3s all ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: .3s all ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .3s all ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="site-header" class="transparent-header effect-two clr sticky-element-original sticky-element-active element-is-not-sticky" data-height="100" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader" style="">



  <div id="site-header-inner" class="clr container">



    <div id="site-logo" class="clr" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Brand">

      htt
      <div id="site-logo-inner" class="clr">

        <a href="https://kutujoy.com/" class="custom-logo-link" rel="home" itemprop="url"><img width="93" height="37" src="https://kutujoy.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/cropped-KutuJoyLogo_93x37.png" class="custom-logo" alt="My Blog" itemprop="logo" srcset="https://kutujoy.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/cropped-KutuJoyLogo_93x37.png 1x, https://kutujoy.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/retina-logo.png 2x"></a>
      </div>
      <!-- #site-logo-inner -->



    </div>
    <!-- #site-logo -->



    <div id="site-navigation-wrap" class="clr">



      <nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation main-navigation clr" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">

        <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="main-menu dropdown-menu sf-menu sf-js-enabled" style="touch-action: pan-y;">
          <li id="menu-item-243" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-238 current_page_item menu-item-243"><a href="https://kutujoy.com/" class="menu-link"><span class="text-wrap">Home</span></a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-244" class="local-scroll menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-244"><a href="https://kutujoy.com/#kutular" class="menu-link"><span class="text-wrap">Kutular</span></a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-245" class="local-scroll menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-245"><a href="https://kutujoy.com/#goal" class="menu-link"><span class="text-wrap">Achieve your goal</span></a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-246" class="local-scroll menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-246"><a href="https://kutujoy.com/#pack" class="menu-link"><span class="text-wrap">Choose your pack</span></a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-247" class="local-scroll menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-247"><a href="https://kutujoy.com/#pricing" class="menu-link"><span class="text-wrap">Pricing</span></a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-256" class="local-scroll menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-256"><a href="https://kutujoy.com/#contact" class="menu-link"><span class="text-wrap">Contact Me</span></a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-250" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-250"><a href="https://kutujoy.com/?page_id=149" class="menu-link"><span class="text-wrap">Blog</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <!-- #site-navigation -->



    </div>
    <!-- #site-navigation-wrap -->




    <div id="oceanwp-mobile-menu-icon" class="clr">




      <a href="#" class="mobile-menu">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        <span class="oceanwp-text">Menu</span>

      </a>



    </div>
    <!-- #oceanwp-mobile-menu-navbar -->


  </div>
  <!-- #site-header-inner -->





</header>
```

I think you cannot visualize anything by running this snippet but if you enter : https://kutujoy.com you understand what I mean when you scroll down.

So what I want is clearly the menu this website has : https://coach.oceanwp.org/

I've got similar results but also it is not responsive when I change screen size (especially logo floats under the 50px header bar).

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no HTML code in the snippet. What is your main problem

Comment: You should visualize https://kutujoy.com its #site-header element is do not work as https://coach.oceanwp.org/ website. What i want is arrange css to work exactly with this site

Comment: Can you elaborate...?\

Comment: So when you enter https://coach.oceanwp.org/ and scroll a little bit down you can see logo,navbar and header shrinks within some transition times and it happens very smoothly. Also, this header and navbar is fully responsive. However, in my website i very closely did this with the code above some margin styles etc. Finally, could not get the exactly the same effects in my website. If someone know how to properly edit this css, i totally appreciated

Comment: I think i find styles of sourced website and applied to my website but i also dont know how to visualize codes. I used chrome developer tools but could not find reliable solution. Any expert can solve this but until now noone has helped me

Comment: The biggest problem of copying code or using wordpress, is that you dont really know whats going on. If this is the case i would recomend you rebuild and find your mistake. If this isnt the case, and you know what is that you are building, I qould love to help you. First ill need to know every js script and css changes that happen on that first scroll

Comment: I rebuilded my website completely not to copy the code. So i shared jquery and css of my menu up to now. You can see in my post above. But i don't know enough css to make my menu that i expected. How i can inform you my js and css changes. I think it tracked by eventlisteners but dont know how to use it properly again.

Comment: i can see jquery and css. But no html to work on. You need to add an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so we can help you.

Comment: I've added html code below post

Comment: Remove your answer before someone down vote you

Comment: I added your html to your question via edit. Now i cant see how your code gives you the end result? Maybe your are missing some css. Take a look

Comment: Gerardo i think i cannot copy whole css related my header. Because, i did not coded all over. You can see related css when you enter kutujoy.com with chrome and using inspect tools.

Answer (score 1):

I can see jquery and css. But no html to work on. You need to add an
Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example so we can help you.– Gerardo BLANCO

Here is my html code :

```html
<header id="site-header" class="transparent-header effect-two clr sticky-element-original sticky-element-active element-is-not-sticky" data-height="100" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader" style="">
<div id="site-header-inner" class="clr container">
    <div id="site-logo" class="clr" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Brand">
        htt
        <div id="site-logo-inner" class="clr">
            <a href="https://kutujoy.com/" class="custom-logo-link" rel="home" itemprop="url"><img width="93" height="37" src="https://kutujoy.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/cropped-KutuJoyLogo_93x37.png" class="custom-logo" alt="My Blog" itemprop="logo" srcset="https://kutujoy.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/cropped-KutuJoyLogo_93x37.png 1x, https://kutujoy.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/retina-logo.png 2x"></a>
        </div><!-- #site-logo-inner -->
    </div><!-- #site-logo -->
    <div id="site-navigation-wrap" class="clr">
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation main-navigation clr" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
            <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="main-menu dropdown-menu sf-menu sf-js-enabled" style="touch-action: pan-y;"><li id="menu-item-243" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-238 current_page_item menu-item-243"><a href="https://kutujoy.com/" class="menu-link"><span class="text-wrap">Home</span></a></li><li id="menu-item-244" class="local-scroll menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-244"><a href="https://kutujoy.com/#kutular" class="menu-link"><span class="text-wrap">Kutular</span></a></li><li id="menu-item-245" class="local-scroll menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-245"><a href="https://kutujoy.com/#goal" class="menu-link"><span class="text-wrap">Achieve your goal</span></a></li><li id="menu-item-246" class="local-scroll menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-246"><a href="https://kutujoy.com/#pack" class="menu-link"><span class="text-wrap">Choose your pack</span></a></li><li id="menu-item-247" class="local-scroll menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-247"><a href="https://kutujoy.com/#pricing" class="menu-link"><span class="text-wrap">Pricing</span></a></li><li id="menu-item-256" class="local-scroll menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-256"><a href="https://kutujoy.com/#contact" class="menu-link"><span class="text-wrap">Contact Me</span></a></li><li id="menu-item-250" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-250"><a href="https://kutujoy.com/?page_id=149" class="menu-link"><span class="text-wrap">Blog</span></a></li></ul>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
    </div><!-- #site-navigation-wrap -->
    <div id="oceanwp-mobile-menu-icon" class="clr">
        <a href="#" class="mobile-menu">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            <span class="oceanwp-text">Menu</span>
        </a>
    </div><!-- #oceanwp-mobile-menu-navbar -->
</div><!-- #site-header-inner -->
</header>
```